# 3D plot of cube in python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm completely new to python and I have to create a 3D plot that has the shape of a cube like the image:

[image]

I have never programmed in python so I'm not even sure what library to use. Can this be solved in matplotlib?

I have to define a function box3d(n) that generates a list of coordinates (3 x n array). The points should be placed along the 12 edges and each line should have n points between -0.5 and 0.5.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 3D Scatter Plot from `matplotlib`, like in the following snippet. Just change the `xs`, `ys`, `zs` arrays with the coordinates of the points that you want to represent.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Fixing random state for reproducibility
np.random.seed(19680801)


def randrange(n, vmin, vmax):
    """
    Helper function to make an array of random numbers having shape (n, )
    with each number distributed Uniform(vmin, vmax).
    """
    return (vmax - vmin)*np.random.rand(n) + vmin

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')

n = 100

# For each set of style and range settings, plot n random points in the box
# defined by x in [23, 32], y in [0, 100], z in [zlow, zhigh].
for m, zlow, zhigh in [('o', -50, -25), ('^', -30, -5)]:
    xs = randrange(n, 23, 32)
    ys = randrange(n, 0, 100)
    zs = randrange(n, zlow, zhigh)
    ax.scatter(xs, ys, zs, marker=m)

ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')
ax.set_zlabel('Z Label')

plt.show()
```

The result of this would be this:

[image: scatter_plot]

Comment: How do I make sure that the points are laid out like in the image? Along the edges of the box with exactly 16 points on each edge?